# Asus Realtek Audio HD keeps popping up

Tags: windows-10, audio, popups, realtek-hd-audio

so i know why this happens it's because the sockets on the front of the Case are not placed properly and it feels like there is some electricity is going on within it. i will send it to repair it but till then Asus Realtek Audio HD keeps popping up literally every time my handsfree's cord moves ever so slightly. and think that i'm plugging/unplugging it every second. i tried to search around but none of the guides had what I HAVE. it looks like this and i just can't find the automatic pop up setting or whatever. if you could tell me how to disable the automatic pop up as a **temporary solution** it would be wonderful.
PLEASE HELP
https://www.phost.us/image/Kd3jC

Answer (score 0):

You have an intermittent connection.

This is caused by applying sideways pressure, over time, on a weak socket.
Sensing sockets have a switch in them, in cheap ones found on many computer cases basically made of little more than a bit of bent wire. Once it's been weakened, then any movement will cause the switch to keep opening & closing, meaning your computer thinks you are plugging & unplugging the jack.

You could try a can of contact cleaner, but usually they need to be replaced. If it's subject to repeated strain, then see if your repair guy can replace it with a higher spec socket. High grade sockets will last decades, but they usually take up much more mounting space, so you might not be able to get one to fit without modifying the case.

Some background on sensing jack sockets - [DigiKey:
A Deep Dive into Audio Jack Switches and Configurations](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/articles/a-deep-dive-into-audio-jack-switches-and-configurations)

Comment: thank you for your information. this will help. i will edit my question now to say what EXACTLY i'm seeking. but then again thank you. i will have this in mind next time i take it for repairing.